# iphone resolution problems

Tags: iphone, css, dimensions

I am developing my first iphone HTML+CSS+JS and i am experimenting some problems,

First, i am confused; It's same resolution in iPhone 3 and iPhone 4?

Because i'm [testing here](http://piscolabis.info/licht/) and i see things really small with my iphone 4

I setted a body min-width: 320px and that doesn't even used 25% of screen,

What  CSS layout/dimension you suggest???

For now i just have

```
body
{
    width: 100%; height:100%;
    font-family: "helvetica";
    min-height:640px; min-wdith:320px;
    background:#000;


}
```

But images with width of 100px really look very small...

Can I separate .CSS for iphone 3 and iphone 4??

Comment: Thanks, i'm having a look. But this website version i'm developing it's only for IOS iphone /23/4 (and maybe ipad, but I don't thing so)

Comment: Physically the iPhone 3 screen is 320x480, the iPhone 4 Retina screen is double that resolution (640x960) but scaling allows native apps to treat it as 320x480 unless they use 2x resolution images.  I'm not sure how much of that applies to web apps though.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone browser defaults to a width of 960 pixels (I think) and scales the screen to fit on the smaller screen of the iPhone.

To fix that, set the viewport in the head section:

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width” />
```

Comment: what do you mean exatcly to 'fix that', what does this meta line of code do? thanks!

Comment: let see if I understood; if I add this line, all iPhones will be displayed the same? :D

Comment: The physical dimensions of your browser window will match the device screen in pixels